# How to create trigger for checking status of application service in zabbix

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I am new in zabbix and wanted to know if someone knows how to create customize application related trigger in zabbix.
Below is my logic which I want to use but I've no idea about syntax.

There is a process called "aviation" so I can check the status by using 
**ps -eaf |grep aviation| wc -l**.
if above command gives output count as 2 it means my process is running perfectly fine else its down.

Can anyone help me to write an expression for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The item key you should use is `proc.num[<name>,<user>,<state>,<cmdline>,<zone>]` (see the [Zabbix agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent?s[]=proc.num) documentation page for all details).

In your case: `proc.num[aviation]` will count the number of procs with 'aviation' name. A trigger expression can be `{*HOST*:proc.num[aviation].last()}<>2`.

Comment: Hi Iron, I tried doing this but it is giving below error. Incorrect item key "proc.num[aviation]" provided for trigger expression on "edgetech01".

Comment: Is the latest data being collected?

Comment: I am not able to save the trigger. if gives above error

Comment: You probably have a typo in the trigger. Did you use the "add" button to create the trigger? Can you include in your question a screenshot of the trigger and the error message?

Comment: You must first create the item, and then reference it in the trigger. You cannot start straight away with a trigger.

Comment: @Richlv Thank you for your response. Can you please let me know the steps of creating item.

Comment: Handholding through all steps would be outside the scope of this site - please consider doing basic research first.